# Async component with socketio blocks initalization

Tags: python, socket.io, python-asyncio, home-assistant

I've implemented a custom component for Home Assistant, which opens the SocketIO stream and feed the event bus with it.

Shorted version:

```py
async def async_setup(hass: HomeAssistant, config: dict):
    sio = AsyncClient()
    await sio.connect(...)

    @sio.on("event")
    async def _handler(data: dict):
        hass.bus.async_fire(...)

    hass.async_create_task(sio.wait())
    return True
```

But when implemented this way it somehow blocks the initialization process. Dashboard is not populated until following line comes up in the log:

```
2022-08-27 19:45:43.586 WARNING (MainThread) [homeassistant.bootstrap] Setup timed out for bootstrap - moving forward
```

**What I'm doing wrong? Should I resign from the async aproach and use threading instead?**

Comment: I managed to find the reason. I will provide detailed answer soon. In short, the reason is that there is a list of tasks which have to be finished to finish bootstrap. To make it not timeout it have to be bypassed.